# Add Source file link to the default ASP.NET Server Error page?

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio, browser

Has anyone ever thought to attempt to modify the default ASP.NET Server error page to provide a link BACK to the error source in Visual Studio?

Consider the following standard error page in ASP.NET:

> ---
>
> Server Error in '/myproject'
>   Application.
>
> Invalid object name 'usp_DoSomething'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Invalid object name 'usp_DoSomething'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 4323:                    cmd.CommandText = "usp_DoSomething";
> Line 4324:
> Line 4325:                    using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
> Line 4326:                    {
> Line 4327:                        if (dr != null)
> ```
>
> Source File:
>   c:\development\myproject\myproject.components\providers\sql\sqldataprovider.cs
>   Line: 4325
>
> ---

When an error like this is generated, the HTML has the source back to the file the error occurs in and the line number. Has anyone ever written or thought of writing some mechanism to turn the text into a link back to the error in Visual Studio?

I've never seen anything that does it, but it just seems like it would be a helluva nice feature and I think about it in the back of my mind every time an error occurs when I have to manually go find it in the source. It would just be nice to be able to click a link to take me straight there.

Anyone written any, or know of any solutions for this. I use Chrome or Firefox as my browsers of choice, but I'd even consider using IE again if someone found a plugin that did this.

Thanks,

Max

Comment: When you are running the site through VS of course it just takes you to the offending line. Outside of that the link would somehow need to identify the process to attach to, the solution for which the source file is a part and whether that exists on your current system (I know, we all update web.config to remove this message when deploying). That's a lot of effort compared to debugging on your dev system from within VS, not sure I see a driver for this.

Comment: I was thinking something much simpler... My thought was just a browser plugin that detected whether you were on an asp.net error page and was able to turn the source file line into a hyperlink that took you to the offending page. moving down to the error line would be an added bonus, but less critical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had been hoping for some means of hacking the error page to turn this:

c:\development\myproject\myproject.components\providers\sql\sqldataprovider.cs Line: 4325

into a link back into my source code in Visual Studio... being that the file name and line number is provided. I was thinking of a browser plugin or something, but apparently no one has built anything like that before... oh well. Was worth a shot.

Comment: if you ever find something like that, please do post it here. Navigating big projects is a challenge. I've been looking, and I'm sure others have as well :)